# which program on windows 10 use location service

Tags: windows-10, location-services

Recently, a small circle often appears unexpectedly on taskbar (lower-right corner of screen) in Windows 10, which indicates that location service is invoked ("Your location is currently in use"). I'd like to know which program on Windows 10 can use location service and how to disable it if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can control which programs have access to Location information (Using sensors on your laptop/tablet or other means on your desktop). To do this on Windows 10.

1. Search for Location and Privacy

[image]
2. Scroll down to locate "Choose which apps can access your precise location"

[image]

One thing to remember though, this way you can only control apps that use Windows Location Services, apps like Chrome trying to determine your location based on your IP etc wont show up in the notification that you mention.

Comment: I am not sure which should be changed. All specific apps are not allowed to access my location, but  "Allow apps to access your location" is set to "on". Also "Allow access to location on this device" is currently set to "on".

Comment: Should I turn off "Allow access to location on this device" or "Allow apps to access your location"?

Comment: If you care about privacy turn both off.

Comment: But will some apps like google map work? I ask this because I feel appearance of small circle is bit annoying, but it happens recently.